# linkbutton in gridview has different id and do postback event target it should be same?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;grid1$ctl02$lkbDelete&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
id="grid1_lkbDelete_0"
```

full link is:

`<a onclick="javascript:return PopupDialouge(&#39;&lt;b>Are you sure you want to delete this Record?&lt;/b>\nbecause all Process related comments for this record\nwill be deleted.&#39;,&#39;Confirmation&#39;,&#39;Delete&#39;,&#39;Cancel&#39;,this,&#39;ui-icon-alert&#39;);" id="grid1_lkbDelete_0" name="lkbDel" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;grid1$ctl02$lkbDelete&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Delete</a>`

Actually i want to `custom postback` by capturing `eventargument` but here i can get only event target which should be same as event target but its different so I can't cause `manual postback`

Comment: can you post the full html tag

Comment: sorry,i cant ,is there anything else that can make it clear to you

Answer (score 1):

i did it myself i changed gridview clientid mode from static to auto then i replaced underscores _ from linkbtn id to doller $ then it worked.

```
var ctlid=this.id.replace(/_/g,'$');
function postback(){
__dopostback(ctlid,'');
}
```